# C - Change Letter in String

Tags: c, string, replace, character

I have the following application written in C:

The application basically presents the user with a word containing one incorrect letter.  The user is requested to provide the position of the incorrect letter and replace it with a new letter.

The problem is that if I try to change letter number 4 (array index 3), the new word would be Act instead of Actually.  If I do it programmatically, that is, change this line

```
string[letter_number - 1] = change;
```

to this

```
string[letter_number - 1] = 'u'
```

everything works fine.  How can I solve this problem please?  Thanks.

Comment: You are discarding the return value of `scanf`. This is a serious programming error, and there's little point guessing around until you fix this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace your `scanf_s` by a simple `scanf` and you will be done. Or else you can use

```
scanf_s("%d ", ...);
```

and remove the `getchar();`

This works for me :

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
  char string[9] = "Actwally";
  int letter_number;
  char change;

  printf("---Spot the Odd Letter Out---\n\n");
  printf("The word below contains one letter which is incorrect:\n\n");
  printf("Word: %s\n\n\n", string);
  printf("Please provide the position of the incorrect letter and propose a new   letter\n\n");
  printf("Position of incorrect letter: ");
  scanf("%d ", &letter_number);
  printf("\nProposed new letter: ");
  scanf("%c ", &change);
  string[letter_number - 1] = change;
  printf("\n\nThe new word looks like this %s\n\n\n", string); 
  if(strcmp("Actually", string) == 0)
  {
    printf("You are right!  Congratulations!");
  }
  else
  {
    printf("Sorry, but you have not guessed the word.  Better luck next time!");
  }
  printf("\n\n\nPlease press enter to exit the program");
  getchar();
}
```

Comment: Thanks.  Now I can finally remove getchar(). But my problem still persists :(

Comment: Thank you so much.  Your answer helped me to solve the problem :)

Answer (score 0):

Verify that your inputs are correct before using them. It sounds as if `change` gets set to 0, terminating the string.

I'm not sure about your `getchar()` calls between the `scanf()` calls, they could lose input.

Comment: Without the getchar(), the program does not allow me to provide the second input (the new letter) for some reason or another.  Is there a way around it?  I am kind a newbie to C.  Moreover, I am programming in Visual Studio.  Does this create any problems?

Comment: I don't think the getchar has an effect though as the program changes the string at the correct position, so the value in letter_number is not lost.  The problem lies with the value in change.

Comment: @Matthew, lose the `get_char` and write the `scanf` with `" %c"` (with space before %) to skip whitespace.

Comment: or write the previous one with "%d ", but anyway replace the scanf_s

Answer (score 0):

Matthew,

Basically I tested your code in GCC compiler. I was in need to change the following things to make it work

- The **newline character** in the "scanf_s" shouldn't be there. The reason for this is as follows. ***If a white space character (include spaces, newline and tab characters) is present within the format specifiers, the scanf function will read and ignore (from stdin) any whitespace characters encountered before the next non-whitespace character*** . As a consequence of this, in this specific use case; your program execution will wait **infinitely** in this scanf statement even after you have entered your input followed by an enter key.

> > scanf_s("%c\n", &change); //Change this as below
> >
> > scanf("%c", &change);

- As per me there is less purpose to use "getchar" after scanfs. The most proper way should be flush the input buffer after the first scanf, so that the second scanf actually expects user input rather to picking from the input buffer.

**PS: Please be aware that fflush(stdin) wont work with GCC.**